# MySQL Triggers to Disable A User Account

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a MySQL Trigger to disable someone's account if they have logged in to the site 3 times.  I have tried to create this trigger using the following code, but it is not setting is_active to 0 no matter what times_logged_in is.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE users SET is_active=0 WHERE NEW.is_code=1 
AND NEW.times_logged_in>=3
AND NEW.user_id=user_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hit a limitation of MySQL. Your table `users` invokes the trigger (`AFTER UPDATE ON users`), therefore the triggered code cannot modify it. See the [MySQL-Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger,
>   it is not permitted to modify a table
>   that is already being used (for
>   reading or writing) by the statement
>   that invoked the function or trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where `user_id` comes from in your trigger, looks like an extraneous check, try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE users SET is_active=0 WHERE NEW.is_code=1 
  AND NEW.times_logged_in>=3
END;
```

Also, be sure that `is_code = 1` is actually matching on the users you're updating, if it's not, it won't update any rows.

Comment: I have tried your code, but it is still not working.  I have also double checked that is_code = 1 is matching, but the trigger still does not seem to be doing anything.

Comment: @Mike D - The `is_code = 1` is matching the **update statment**, or the existing row?, same for the `times_logged_in`?

Comment: The is_code = 1 is matching the existing row.  The times_logged_in is matching the update statement, it is being incremented by 1.

Comment: @Mike - Is is_code matching the updated row?  Not sure what is_code is referring to.  Posting the update statement may help here as well.

Comment: is_code=1 means that the user should be logging in with an access code instead of a user name or password.

The update statement is as follows:

    UPDATE users SET times_logged_in=times_logged_in+1
    WHERE user_id=10

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON users 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.is_code=1 AND NEW.times_logged_in>=3 THEN
   SET NEW.is_active=0;
END IF;
END;
```