# automatically lock user account in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I want to lock user accounts automatically when user failed to login after 3 attempts with wrong username/password in mysql database.

I tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger 
BEFORE UPDATE ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN IF NEW.is_code=1 AND NEW.times_logged_in>=3
THEN SET NEW.is_active=0;
END IF;
END;
```

but I am getting

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1'

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2588336/1393862

Comment: Down voted as there is not enough detail. Please provide sample code that you have tried. Also provide details on problems you are currently facing.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.is_code=1 AND NEW.times_logged_in>=3 THEN
   SET NEW.is_active=0;
END IF;
END; just I tried with this but I am getting the error ' You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1'

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to change the delimiter before the create trigger statement.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ...

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: it's not work still please suggest, one more thing I am not understating where the columns are the three columns are not in 'MYSQL.USERS', please clarify any one. I just copied the script from this site only

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.is_code=1 AND NEW.times_logged_in>=3 THEN
   SET NEW.is_active=0;
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER; Now it is executed I got error " Triggers can not be created on system tables " any suggestions plz

Comment: You are trying to install a trigger for the database called mysql which keeps the system tables. First create a custom database for your data using the mysqladmin program.